# On content, choose the taxonomy parent and display all the children

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type with a taxonomy field based on a hierarchical taxonomy with 3 levels. I use Simple Hierarchical Select (SHS) to select and display the terms.

I want to have a view that displays the chosen terms on each content page, but I also want when I choose the parent term to show all its children without selecting every one of them.

I made a content view with a Content:ID contextual filter. As a formatter I use SHS but it displays only the selected term at the selected depth, no other options. I tried with another contextual filter on the taxonomy depth, also with another taxonomy view to take the children of a term and then use views field view to embed it on the primary view, no success at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in the future, I managed to solve this using the [Entity Reference Tree Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_tree) module, which provides the exact functionality as described on question.